# PgSync updates not syncing to ES Index intermittently

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, pgsync

PG Sync is intermittently failing to  sync the data specifically for few complex relational tables in PostgreSql. Everything worked fine in lower environments for the same version.
So we want to understand How exactly the PG Sync works ?
Does it depends on replication slots to sync the data for the live updates happening in DB ?
Also I see triggers created by PG Sync for every table.
How exactly is this different ? What is the use of these triggers & what is the use of replication slots ?
If live updates are not syncing properly, is it because of triggers or replication slots fault ?

I use PG Sync - 2.2.1

Comment: How it's failing, please provide more details